# Apple TV user agent string. Can anyone provide it?

Tags: web, user-agent, apple-tv

I need to build support for Apple TV in a web app.  But I can't seem to find the user agent string for its browser anywhere.

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Sample UA is

User-Agent: iTunes-AppleTV/4.1

The 4.1 being the software version. There can be characters after the version so you need to take that into account when doing matching.

Answer (score 2):

The second generation Apple TV does not have Web browser functionality built into it.  (I don't know if the first generation ATV did or not.)

Answer (score 1):

[Google searches](https://www.google.com/search?q=AppleTV/2.4+user-agent) reveal:

```
AppleTV/2.4
```

is a valid Apple TV user-agent string.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume you have an Apple TV for testing. Couldn't you just write a page that displays the user-agent and connect to it from the Apple TV?